# Determine the probability of beverages

Tags: probability

An ice box freezes $24$ cans of juice drinks : $6$ cucumber juice , $6$ apple juice , $3$ watermelon juice , $3$ orange juice and $6$ ginger ale.

If one can is drawn at random, what is the probability of getting

1. A can of apples juice?
2. A can of cucumbers juice or a can of ginger ale?
3. A can that is neither cucumber juice , apple juice nor ginger ale?

Comment: Please include your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but my way is learning from the answer : )

Comment: I think you will find that you will always learn quicker if you try to solve the problem yourself first. Also, per [site policy](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you are actually required to include your own efforts.

Comment: thanks for your good advices. i really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $P(\text{apple}) = \frac{6}{24}=\frac{1}{4}$

2)$P(\text{cucumber OR ginger})=\frac{6+6}{24}=\frac{1}{2}$

3)$P(\text{not(cucumber OR ginger OR apple)})=1-P(\text{cucumber OR ginger OR apple})=1-\frac{6+6+6}{24}=\frac{1}{4}$

It is just to apply the quantity of the wanted cans between the total number of cans (it's called Laplace's rule). For the last one I am just doing the calculation for the fact that you drwn each of the cans and then substracting it to one to have the complement.